# Yii removing application directory name from URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, yii, appfog

Okay seems like this is a pretty common problem, but I can't find a definitive solution on the forums.

My Yii is set up like this

```
/webroot/framework
/webroot/app
/webroot/requirements
```

The app folder hosts the yii application

however my url looks like : site[dot]com/app/site/index

How do I remove the 'app' portion from the URL.

I tried moving my .htaccess file to the webroot folder and it redirects but 'app' still shows up in the url

Here are the contents of /webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # need this for AMZN ELB or get a infinite redirect loop 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^localhost$
  RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule . /app/index.php 
</IfModule>
```

I would be easy if I could just change my webroot to /webroot/app but I can't control that. Thanks for any help..

This is launched on appfog so I can't control the webroot, or have the framework folder live one directory above the webroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can move all files from /webroot/app to /webroot/ (and place yii at /webroot/yii).

Comment: yeah i think the trick is just moving some files around so it's not the typical directory structure. I'm a little uncomfortable doing that but doesn't seem like there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by going on the config like config/main.php and putting:

```
'request'=>array(
        'baseUrl'=>'',

    ),
     'urlManager'=>array(
        'baseUrl'=>'',
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'appendParams' => true,
        'rules'=>array(

        ),
    ),  'request'=>[
        'baseUrl'=>'',

    ],
     'urlManager'=>array(
        'baseUrl'=>'',
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'appendParams' => true,
        'rules'=>array(

        ),
    ),
```

Just came back to Yii and faced this problem again

Answer (score 1):

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430006/running-yii-from-subdir-remove-subdir-with-htacces-while-css-js-and-existin). 
Placing the 'app' contents in webroot/ however is not an option for me because I need it to be portable and in the near future I'll have other 'apps' in the webroot/ running on the same webroot/framework.

I managed to redirect example.com to example.com/app and had the /app part removed from the URL. I'm redirected to the default controller/action. But when I click on a link to (e.g.) example.com/site/login it still brings me to the default controller/action.

My webroot/.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^application/
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/$1 [L]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# RewriteRule ^.*$ application/index.php does not 'remove' the directory with this??
RewriteRule ^$ application [L]
```

Maybe it helps you out? 
And since I'm not that much of a .htaccess expert I was wondering if you found a better solution by now ?